# Ridged body no physics

Tags: game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a static object that flys through the air that needed collision. So i changed it to a ridged body but it still has physics and wont fly anymore. Is there a way to have a ridged body with collision with no physics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable gravity for Rigid Bodys in the "Scene" settings.